# Hanging transaction when open two SQL connections in nested transaction scopes

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to understand what is wrong in the code below:

```
using (var scope1 = new TransactionScope())
{
    var connection1 = new SqlConnection("...");
    connection1.Open();

    using (var scope2 = new TransactionScope())
    {

        SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection("...");
        connection2.Open();

        connection2.Close();
        scope2.Complete();

    }

    connection1.Close();
    scope1.Complete();
}
```

An application is quite complex therefore exists nested blocks of the `TransactionScope`. In the code above, when a connection has opened the transaction is created in SQL Server so actually, two transactions are created, because the connection is opened two times.

I checked this by calling the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1
```

When the ambient transaction in scope1 has finished there is still one transaction in the database. The transaction created by the connection2.Close() is still hanging. My question is why this transaction still exists and how to correct the code.

**EDIT:**

I guess using one SQL connection defined outside the `TransactionScope` can be an answer, but maybe exists something better?

Comment: Are you getting an exception from opening connection 2?  Try adding a catch to connection 2 code and see if you are getting an exception.  Using statements sometimes mask exceptions.  I think you are getting an exception before connection 2 closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will require a distributed transaction because you have two separate SqlConnection objects open at the same time.  If you close the SqlConnection before starting the second TransactionScope, the initial connection and transaction will be reused, and you won't need a DTC trasnaction.

Anyway, I think this is a harmless side-effect of having DTC transaction, which are tracked a little differently.  Check

```
  select st.session_id, is_local, is_enlisted, at.transaction_state
  from sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st
  join sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at
    on at.transaction_id = st.transaction_id
```

For me that outputs a row for the second session opened (spid 65), and indicates that the transaction has committed.

```
session_id  is_local is_enlisted transaction_state
----------- -------- ----------- -----------------
65          0        1           6
```

transaction_state=6 indicates that the transaction has commited. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-active-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017